# SQL table JOIN on difference of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and i need to query the difference on one field on both them and then to join the result with one of the tables , those are my tables :
                                     
              -----------------------------------------------
 
**Products :**                       | ProductId(PK)  | ProductName               | 
                                                    -----------------------------------------------
                                                   |             1                    | Pension Funds     |
                                                    -----------------------------------------------
                                                    |             2                     | Study Funds           |
               
                                     -----------------------------------------------
                                                    |              3                    | Provident Funds    |
                                                     -----------------------------------------------

                                               ------------------------------------------------------------------
**Comissions :**           | SellerId(PK1) |   ProductId(PK2)(FK) | Comission  |
                                               ------------------------------------------------------------------
                  
                              |            11                 |                    1                             |        10            |
                                               ------------------------------------------------------------------
                          
                              |           11                 |                    2                             |        20            |
                                               ------------------------------------------------------------------
               
                                |          22                 |                    3                             |        30            |
                                               ------------------------------------------------------------------
              
                                 |           33                 |                    1                             |        10            |
                                               ------------------------------------------------------------------
                             
                  |           33                 |                    2                             |        20            |
                                               ------------------------------------------------------------------
                                               |           33                 |                    3                             |        30            |
                                               ------------------------------------------------------------------

When I have a **SellerId** i need to query all the **ProductId**'s and **ProductName**s that the seller **don't sale** 

**e.g. if** given **SellerId = 11** as a result I should  get back one record **(3,Provident Funds)** 
       **if** given **SellerId = 22** as a result I should get two records **(1,Pension Funds)** and **(2,Study Funds)** 
       
**if** given **SellerId = 33 no records** should be returned .

for now I have this :
 **SELECT ProductId FROM Products 
EXCEPT
 SELECT ProductId FROM Comissions WHERE SellerId = @SellerId**

this query return the differnce of **ProductId**'s , I need a help to join it with **Products** table on **ProductId**'s .

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
    WHERE ProductId NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM Comissions WHERE SellerId = @SellerId)
```

Comment: If we have not any specific seller id and want to get all list of that types then ??

Comment: What do you mean? If you want all products then you don't need WHERE condition at all

Comment: ohhho 

11 3 Provident Funds
22 1 Pension Funds
22 2 Study Funds


I want this type of data

Comment: @NavneetVerma The OP isn't asking for such a query...?

Comment: I am asking just for knowledge

Comment: Thank you very much , you solved it so quickly , it works also if seller not exists in the Commissions table , exactly what i need!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the answer given by dotnetom, this is by using [**Exists**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188336%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT ProductId
        FROM Comissions
        WHERE SellerId = @SellerId
            AND ProductId = Products.ProductId
        )
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a0d1/4)

Comment: what is the difference between NOT EXISTS and NOT IN ??

Comment: @DimaRudaev: The WHERE clause in NOT EXISTS is satisfied if no rows are returned by the subquery. To understand it in detail i suggest you to go thru [this link](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).